# Excel, adding numbers from two columns and then multiplying with a third one, while referencing from different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a way to first add numbers from two different columns (as in A:A+B:B) and then multiply the resulting number with a third column, all this while the columns are in a different sheet.

Multiplying two columns works with SUMPRODUCT, but I fail to make the function work by first adding up two columns.

So, while this works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Sheet 2'!A:A,'Sheet2'!B:B)
```

I can't make any of these work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet 2'!A:A+'Sheet2'!C:C),'Sheet 2'!B:B)
=SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet 2'!A:A+'Sheet3'!A:A),'Sheet 2'!B:B)
=SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet 2'!A:A+'Sheet3'!D:D),'Sheet 2'!B:B)
```

I guess I'm searching in the wrong direction. I use Excel 2010. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great usecase for a CSE/Array formula:

```
=(Sheet2!A:A + Sheet3!A:A)*Sheet2!B:B
```

When entering that hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter. It will get some curly braces around it so you know it's an Array formula and it should calculate.

---

If you want to do this with `=SumProduct` you'll just have to get more crafty with it. I like to think about sumproduct as multiplying a bunch of groups/arrays together and then adding the results. Here you have two arrays where you want each element to be multiplied together and the results added up.

- Group 1: The results of Sheet1!A:A summed with Sheet2!C:C
- Group 2: The values in Sheet1!B:B

This would take the form:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A:A) + (Sheet2!B:B)) * Sheet1!C:C)
```

Comment: Hey, JNevill and thanks for the quick answer. Sadly, none of those seem to work, there is just a #VALUE error...

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: 2010 and I must admit that it is theoretically possible that I am doing something wrong with the formulas You provided, but I did a thorough attempt to make them work.

Comment: I can't recall exactly, but I believe it wasn't until Excel 2013 that you could toss the entire column into a `sumproduct`. I'm not sure about array formulas though. Try `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5000) + (Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5000)) * Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5000)`